# Potential legal issues with storing Social Security/Insurance Numbers (SSNs/SINs)?

Tags: security

A client using our system has requested that we store the SSNs/SINs of the end users in our database. Currently, we store minimal information about users (name, email address, and optionally, country), so I'm not overly concerned about a security breach - however, I have a suspicion there could be legal issues about storing SSNs and not taking "appropriate" measures to secure them (coming from Australia, this is my first encounter with them). Is this a valid concern?

I also read on the Wikipedia page about SINs (Canada's equivalent to SSNs) that it should ONLY be used when absolutely necessary and definitely shouldn't be used as a general identifier, or similar.

So, are there any potential legal issues about this sort of thing? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: To what country does this question apply? The current answers do *not* apply for all countries.

Comment: For the USA - but if you have different information for different countries, please do share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The baseline recommendation would be to:

- Inform the user that you are storing their SSN before they use your site/application. **Since the request appears to be to collect the information *after the fact*, the users should have a way to opt out of your system before they log in or before they put in their SSN**
- Issue a legal guarantee that you will not provide, sell, or otherwise distribute the above information (along with their other personal information of course)
- Have them check a checkbox stating that they understand that you really are storing their SSNs

but the most important part would probably be:

- Hire a lawyer well-versed with legal matters over the web

Answer (score 3):

Funny thing about SSNs... the law that created them, also clearly defined what they may be used for (basically tax records, retirement benefits, etc.) and what they are not allowed to be used for - everything else.

So the fact that the bank requires your SSN to open a checking account, your ISP asks for it for high speed internet access, airlines demand it before allowing you on a plane, your local grocery/pub keeps a tab stored by your SSN - that is all *illegal*. Shocking, isn't it...
All the hooha around identity theft, and how easy it is thanks to a single, unprotected "secret" that "uniquely" identifies you across the board (not to mention that its sometimes used as **authentication**) - should never have been made possible.

Comment: Over the years, the law has been modified to where just about any use is perfectly legal. See here: http://query.nytimes.com/gst/fullpage.html?res=9C02EFD71039F935A15754C0A96E958260

Comment: That may be so - but it should never have been. The fact remains, a non-secret is still used as unique identification, and often as authentication. THAT is still wrong.

Comment: @AviD to the best of my knowledge the banks are _forced_ to require it for both taxation (interest on account) and also the post 9/11 laws regarding knowing their customers.

Answer (score 1):

Some good warning stated already here.

I'll just add that speaking of SIN (Canada's Social Insurance Number) codes, I believe it's possible to have collisions between a SIN and a SSN (in other words the same number, but two different people/countries). It shouldn't be a surprise since these are separate codification systems, but I somehow can imagine some doing data entry that may be inclined to stick a SIN into a SSN field and vis-versa (think international students in college/university as one instance - I was told by a DBA friend that he saw this happen).

A given information system may be designed to not allow duplicates, and either way, you can see why there might be confusion and data integrity issues (using a SSN column as a unique key? Hmm).

Answer (score 0):

Way too many organizations in the USA use SSNs as unique identifiers for people, despite the well-documented problems with them. Unless your application actually has something to do with government benefits, there's no good reason for you to store SSns.

Given that so many organizations (mis)use them to identify people for things like credit checks, you really need to be careful with them. With nothing more than someone's name, address, and SSN, it's pretty easy to get credit under their name, and [steal their identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_security_number#Identity_theft).

The legal issues are along the lines of getting sued into oblivion for any leak of personal information that contains SSNs.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd avoid them like the plague, or figure out some very very secure way to store them. Additionally (not a legal expert by any extent but..) if you can put in writing somewhere that you are no way responsible if any of this gets out.

Comment: Technically if you request for that information, that implies that you are responsible for it, so if it gets out, whether or not you have that disclaimer, you can still be sued to kingdom come

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you want to be sure that SSNs are never emailed without some protection. I think the built-in "password to open" in Excel is enough, legally. I think email is the weakest link, at least in my industry.

Every now and then, there is a news item "Laptop Stolen: Thousands of SSNs Possibly Compromised." It's my great fear that it could be my laptop. I put all SSN containing files in a PGP-protected virtual drive.

You do have good security on your database, don't you? If not, why not?